# Unable to display data in Vue.js form after pulling from Cloud Firestore

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I've a contact form in my Vue.js template using the v-model inside of my textfields to display the retreived data. In my script, inside of the "created" block I retrieve a doc from Firestore using the passed in docid.

I then run a check to see if a valid object is found, and I can even output the found object to the console.

The problem is that I cannot save the object found from Firestore (in my case the "applicant" object) to the applicant object I've previously defined in the data block. For example, I can find and output the doc's first_name value to the console (e.g., `console.log(doc.data().applicant.first_name)`) but I cannot save the value to the `this.applicant.first_name` bound to the first_name textfield.

You can see from the error console that I'm able to output the data but cannot bind it to the applicant.first_name.

[image: console_error_results]

The code is below. (*I'm wondering if it has anything to do with the fact that the code is run in the "created" block before the page is rendered .. I don't know.*)

**Many thanks in advance for anyone's help!**

**Template**

```
<template>
  <v-container
    fluid>
    <v-text-field v-model="applicant.first_name" label="First Name"/>
    <v-text-field v-model="applicant.middle_name" label="Middle Name"/>
    <v-text-field v-model="applicant.last_name" label="Last Name"/>
    <v-text-field v-model="applicant.email" label="Email"/>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

**Script**

```
<script>
  import db from '@/components/firebase/firebaseInit.js'

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        applicant: {
          first_name: '',
          middle_name: '',
          last_name: '',
          email: ''
        },
      }
    created: function () {
      db.collection("applicants").doc(this.$route.params.id)
        .get()
        .then( function(doc) {
          console.log('Inside First call');

          if (doc.exists) {
            console.log("Document data:", doc.data())
            // console.log(doc.data().first_name)

            this.applicant.first_name = doc.data().first_name
            this.applicant.middle_name = doc.data().middle_name
            this.applicant.last_name = doc.data().last_name
            this.applicant.email = doc.data().email
          } else {
            // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
            console.log("No such document!");
          }
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
         console.log("Error getting document:", error);
        })

    }

  }
</script>
```

Comment: I could be completely wrong here, but isnt the function in `then(...)` in a different scope?
try to cache your object `this` at the beginning of created (for example: `this _this = this`) and replace in `this(...)` `this` with `_this`.

Comment: Wow. Thanks @PolygonParrot - that was exactly it. I added a simple "`let _this = this`" to the start of the created function and changed the values late to `_this.applicant.first_name = doc ...` and it worked. Can't believe I got hit by the "this" bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, @PolygonParrot for the answer.
Added the `let _this = this` and the subsequent `_this.applicant...` values below.

```
created: function () {
      let _this = this
      db.collection("applicants").doc(this.$route.params.id)
        .get()
        .then( function(doc) {
          console.log('Inside First call');

          if (doc.exists) {
            console.log("Document data:", doc.data())
            // console.log(doc.data().first_name)

            _this.applicant.first_name = doc.data().first_name
            _this.applicant.middle_name = doc.data().middle_name
            _this.applicant.last_name = doc.data().last_name
            _this.applicant.email = doc.data().email
          } else {
            // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
            console.log("No such document!");
          }
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
         console.log("Error getting document:", error);
        })
```