# Data not display inside vuetify v-text-field with Nuxt & Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

this is a related question which I've asked before:
[Get document data from Firestore and show the data into each of the form input field using Nuxt & Vuetify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69748818/get-document-data-from-firestore-and-show-the-data-into-each-of-the-form-input-f)

I want the data that I've submitted to display on the v-text-field input.

[image: my v-text-field input]

As you can see from the image, I can submit my form and I can get the data accordingly.

Name: siradley_   <-- this come from my firestore

but I want it to display inside the v-text-field input, not outside the input field.

Currently, I still not know how to do it.

Any help on how to do it?

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <v-container>
            <v-layout>
                <v-flex>
                    <v-card>
                        <v-card-text>
                            <v-form>
                                <v-layout>
                                    <v-row>
                                        <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="6" v-for="(test, id) in Test">
                                            <v-text-field
                                            v-model="editedItem.name">{{ test.name }}</v-text-field>
                                            <p>Name: {{ test.name }}</p>
                                        </v-col>
                                        <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="6">
                                            <v-btn @click="test">Test</v-btn>
                                        </v-col>
                                    </v-row>
                                </v-layout>
                            </v-form>
                        </v-card-text>
                    </v-card>
                </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
        </v-container>
    </div>
</template>
```

my script

```html
<script>
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import firestore from "@/plugins/firebasetest";

export default {
    middleware: "authentication",
    layout: 'dashboard',

    data: () => ({
        Test: [
            {
                name: '',
            }            
        ],

        editedItem: {
            name: '',
        } 
    }),

    created() {
        this.readTest();
    },

    methods: {
        readTest() {
            this.Test = [];
            firestore
                .collection('test')
                .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
                .get()
                .then((doc) => {
                    this.Test.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });
                    console.log({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });
                })
        },

        test() {
            var data = {
                name: this.editedItem.name,
            }
            firestore
            .collection('test')
                .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
                .set(data)
                .then((doc) => {
                window.location.reload();
                console.log({ ...doc.data, id: doc.id })
            })
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to update the value `editedItem.name` in your data object after getting the value from the server.

you have two way data binding set on the `v-text-field` (i.e. `v-model`), so you just need to use `v-text-field` like this:

```
<v-text-field v-model="editedItem.name" ></v-text-field>
```

and then in the code after you get the data from the server update the mentioned field in the data:

```
async getDataFromServerExample() {
   const data = await getData();
   this.editedItem.name = data.properFieldFromServerResponse;
}
```

then everything should work fine.

Comment: Hi there Hamid, unfortunately it still not working and im not sure how to really implement your solution into mine. I still not know how to solve it. :(

Answer (score 0):

Finally can solve it hehe.

Referring to this [Unable to display data in Vue.js form after pulling from Cloud Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53688949/unable-to-display-data-in-vue-js-form-after-pulling-from-cloud-firestore) , I now can display my input data inside my v-text-field.

Here's how I do it:

```
<v-form>
    <v-layout>
        <v-row :items="Test">
            <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="6"> 
                <v-text-field
                   v-model="editedItem.name"></v-text-field>
            </v-col>
            <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="6">
                <v-btn @click="test">Test</v-btn>
            </v-col>
         </v-row>
    </v-layout>
</v-form>
```

```
<script>
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import firestore from "@/plugins/firebasetest";

export default {
    middleware: "authentication",
    layout: 'dashboard',

    data: () => ({
        editedItem: {
            name: '',
        } 
    }),

    created() {
        this.readTest();
    },

    methods: {
        readTest() {
            let _this = this;
            firestore
                .collection('test')
                .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
                .get()
                .then((doc) => {
                    if (doc.exists) {
                        console.log("Document data:", doc.data())
                        _this.editedItem.name = doc.data().name    
                    } else {
                       console.log("No Document!"); 
                    }
                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.log("Error :(");
                })
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

I added `let _this = this;` and `_this.editedItem.name = doc.data().name` and it works.